# Installing pip for specific python3 version (3.7) issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, pip

I have installed python 3.7 alongside python 3.9 to use for tensor flow and set 3.7 as my main python version via .bashrc and the alternatives tool.

I cant seem to install tensor flow(or any python module in fact) for python3.7  no matter what command I try, for example:

```
python3 -m pip install tensorflow
python3.7 -m pip install tensorflow
pip3 install tensorflow
pip install tensorflow
pip3.7 install tensorflow
```

None of these commands work and return the error `no module named pip`, I look inside `~/.local/bin` and there is: pip, pip3 and pip3.9 but no pip3.7 and then in `~/.local/lib` there is only a directory for python3.9

Also the current version (for both `python -V` and `python3 -V`) is 3.7.10

I'm using fedora 33 and have tried to look for packages such as python3.7-pip or pip3.7 but no luck there.

Comment: Can you check whats the output of ```python -m pip --version``` ? The documentation here https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/ says pip should come by default

Comment: the output is "usr/bin/python: No module named pip" and the same command but with python3 the output is "usr/bin/python3.7: No module named pip"

Comment: Try installing pip using ```sudo yum install python3-pip```

Comment: the output is that "python-pip-20.2.2.1.fc33.noarch is already installed"

Comment: Ok. Try ```python-pip-20.2.2.1.fc33.noarch install tensorflow```

Comment: states that the command is not found, I also tried to remove pip and python3.9 to try to install pip for python3.7 but it states that it would also remove protected packages: gnome-shell which is strange

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+%22no+module+named+pip%22

Comment: `python3.7 -m ensurepip`

Comment: Or `wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py && python3.7 get-pip.py`